# number formatting in ngModel

Tags: angular, formatting, separator, ngmodel

```html
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="valami.Price">
```

Hi! Is there any simple way to format a number in this case?

now it displays 1000 for example. the goal is to display 1 000.00
i know pipes are not allowed in ngModel so

{{valami.Price | number: 3.2-2}}

is not working here.

the second question is how to replace the thousand separator? the default is ',' what i want to change to ' '. should i write a transform function in the component or, is there any simple way to do that?

thanks

Comment: I think you should be able to use pipes with ngModel like this: `[ngModel]="valami.Price | number: '3.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="updatePrice($event)"`

Comment: thanks. i modified it to
 [ngModel]="valamiPrice | number: '1.2-2'"  (ngModelChange)="valami.Price = $event" and now its working like two-way binding

Comment: But do you want to format it the way you stated inside the form? That could be a problem because then it's not a number anymore...